# Please help with Bulkify code

Tags: trigger, map, bulkification

I need some help to bulkify following code. It works for 1 record when a user would change the field but I am worried that it would hit Governor limits as soon as bulk data load would occur. I am not sure how to change this code to handle 200 records. I have a custom Lookup field(toContact) `custom_InternalReferrerAccount__c` on Account object and I am copying it to

If you can please help with this code, it would be great for my learning. Thanks.

```java
public class custom_UpdateFinservInternalRef {
@InvocableMethod(label='Copy value to Internal referrer field2' description='Gets value from custom Internal Referrer field and writes to FSC Internal Referrer field')
    public static void updateFinservInterRefField(List<Id> AccountIds)
    {
        List<Account> acc = [select id, custom_Employee__c, custom_InternalReferrerAccount__r.email from Account where Account.id in :AccountIds];
        System.debug('debug-sw1:'+acc);
       
        if(acc.size()> 0){
            string conEmailId = acc[0].custom_InternalReferrerAccount__r.email;
            List<User> conEmailIntRef = [select id, email from User Where email= :conEmailId LIMIT 1];
            System.debug('debug-sw3: '+conEmailIntRef + 'and conEmailId is: '+ conEmailId);
            
            if(conEmailIntRef.size()>0){ 
                for(Account a : acc){
                    acc[0].FinServ__ReferredByUser__c=conEmailIntRef[0].Id;
                    System.debug('debug-sw4 Inside loop: '+ acc);
                }
                update acc;
                System.debug('debug-sw5: '+ acc);
            }
                
            }
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? The first query is "FROM Account" and has "WHERE Account.Id" which should be "WHERE Id" instead... Also the only loop is always updating index 0 in the accounts using index 0 in the internal referrer contacts, and that's definitely not appropriate.

Comment: Oh, and the "acc" and "conEmail" lists will be essentially the same (with the exception of a few extra fields in the first one) so I don't know why you're doing this.

Comment: I removed the conEmail list. How can I use map to use 1 SOQL instead of 2 so I won't hit Governor limit. Please see the updated code.
You other point of using index of 0, I am going to remove it so all list items are getting updated. I am going to try to do that. Thanks, this is great help. I have not used map so it would take some time. @Phil W

Comment: can you update the question to complete the explanation of what you are actually trying to do? It is left incomplete above the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement isn't entirely clear, however I'm guessing what you actually want to do is along the following lines:

```
public class custom_UpdateFinservInternalRef {
    @InvocableMethod(Label='Copy value to Internal referrer field2' Description='Gets value from custom Internal Referrer field and writes to FSC Internal Referrer field')
    public static void updateFinservInterRefField(List<Id> accountIds) {
        // Query all the accounts with the referrer account email address
        List<Account> accounts = [
                SELECT Id, custom_Employee__c, FinServ__ReferredByUser__c, custom_CIBCInternalReferrerAccount__r.email
                        FROM Account
                        WHERE Id IN :accountIds
        ];

        if (!accounts.isEmpty()) {
            // Build a collection of all the referrer account email addresses
            Set<String> emailAddresses = new Set<String>();
            
            for (Account account : accounts) {
                // This uses the safe navigation operator to avoid null pointer exceptions
                // (in case there's no referrer account)
                String emailAddress = account.custom_CIBCInternalReferrerAccount__r?.email;
                
                // Don't want to consider null values
                if (emailAddress != null) {
                    emailAddresses.add(emailAddress);
                }
            }

            // Now get all users with the given email addresses. Note that the last
            // user with a given email address will be used when multiple users share
            // the same email address
            List<User> users = [
                    SELECT Id, Email
                            FROM User
                            WHERE Email IN :emailAddresses
            ];

            if (!users.isEmpty()) {
                // Turn this into a map for quick lookup from the user email address to the User itself
                Map<String, User> usersByEmailAddress = new Map<String, User>();
                
                for (User user : users) {
                    usersByEmailAddress.put(user.Email, user);
                }

                // Work out which accounts need to be updated and update them
                List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

                for (Account account : accounts) {
                    User user = usersByEmailAddress.get(account.custom_CIBCInternalReferrerAccount__r?.email);
                    
                    if (user != null && account.FinServ__ReferredByUser__c != user.Id) {
                        account.FinServ__ReferredByUser__c = user.Id;
                        accountsToUpdate.add(account);
                    }
                }

                update accountsToUpdate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NB: Since I don't have your object model changes I cannot execute (let alone test) this code so no guarantee it is correct or doing what you want.

Comment: Phil, This is great! Let me work with your code. I will test it in my environment and make any changes since I didn't give you full overview of our requirements (sorry about that).  THANK YOU!

Comment: Requirements:
Financial Service Cloud comes with a field finserv_InternalReferrer which is a lookup to User object. Problem with that out of box field is that it only looks up active users. 
We loaded all users (active and inactive)  in Contact object and created a lookup field "custom_InternalReferrerAccount" that looks up to Contact object.
Our code is taking the contact and querying User object based on email, finding the user  ID and writing it to out of box field finserv_InternalReferrer.

Comment: Phil,
Thank YOU! I really appreciate your help to fix my code while making it bulkify. This worked perfectly. One last question I have 2 queries in my code, if I get 200 records in my code through bulk data load job, would my code execute 400 SOQL queries?

Comment: This is an invokable method, so is expected to be call from a flow (or process builder). These automatically bulkify the invocation of the method when the flow processes multiple records. The implementation I have provided will only perform the two SOQL queries for each call to the method. If the flow collects 200 records or just 1, the same number of queries will be used - I.e. 2.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation again. I now understand that the call from flow would do the bulkification. Appreciate your help.